# Differentiability on a closed interval proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function that is differentiable on $[-p, p]$ for all $0
>  \le p < R$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $(-R, R)$.

It seems obvious to me that this is true but strangely enough I am not sure how to prove it, could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x \in (-R,R)$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ because $\exists$ $r \in (0,R)$ such that $x \in [-r,r]$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability in an open interval means differentiability at every point $c$ of the interval. Every point $c$ in the interval $(-R,R)$ is contained in a suitable interval $[-A,A]$ for a suitable $A$.  For instance one can choose $A=\frac{1}{n}\lfloor nR \rfloor$ for $n$ large enough.